# How can we set our vs code prettier on save format to the rules mentioned in .prettierrc

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

[image]
[image]

1st image : before save
2nd image : after saving formats to some default config by vs code

I am getting lint errors after saving the file(right side). Even after fixing it and then saving again goes back to the error state.
How do we make our vs code editor adapt to the rules mentioned by the project and not according to local setting in vs code, probably in `.prettierrc`

Answer (score 0):

Open vs code settings (file->preferences->settings) search for `Editor: Format On Save` and click on checkbox

And try to set `Prettier: Config Path` option to `.prettierrc`

Comment: This is just format using the default rules , I want it according to how it's mentioned in local config

Comment: Try setting `Prettier: Config Path` option to .prettierrc